# Can I call a server-side method using javascript without causing a postback?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have JavaScript code that calls a method in ASP.NET. Basically, I have a `SqlDataSource` connected to a `GridView`, and I want to change the `SelectCommand` of the `DataSource` without causing a postback.

Right now, I am using `__dopostback` method, but as I said I don't want the page to reload. I just want the `GridView` to update. Is this possible?

Comment: Change the select command in what way?

Comment: I am getting some values from javascript based on which I have to change my Gridview (which is a user control). So I am doing this :'__doPostBack(pageId, query)'; The select command takes the value of 'query'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not how is done. There are many approaches to this but the easiest is to enclose your content inside an UpdatePanel and drop a ScriptManager on your page.

for example:

```
<asp:ScriptManager id="mymanager" runat="server" />

<asp:UpdatePanel id="mainPanel" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>

<! -- Put your content here -->

</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Now all interactions on your page will be done via Ajax.

**Better approach** (the one I use currently)

Use jQuery to make your Ajax calls in conjunction with a Web Service.

Sample code:

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class MyWebService: System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public List<BusinessObject> GetSomeData(int dataID)
    {
        //Invoke your business layer and get some data here
        List<BusinessObject> result = BusinessLayer.GetSomeData();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Using jQuery on the client-side, you can do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "MyWebService.svc/GetSomeData",
    data: {'dataId': you_id_here },
    success: function(result) {
        //result.d will contain an array of BusinessObject in JSON format
        //You can iterate through this list and populate your html using this data.
        //You can either use jQuery templates
        //or one of the many jQuery plugins for tabular data.
        //I use datatables:
        //http://datatables.net/
        for(int i=0;i<result.d.length; i++)
        {
            //do something here if you want to iterate one by one constructing your
            //html
        }
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
           //display error here
        });
    }
});
```

I highly recommend looking at these links:

1. http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/
2. http://encosia.com/simplify-calling-asp-net-ajax-services-from-jquery/

Comment: @Raynos: Tell me about it!!! I don't use it for that reason, but is the easiest to implement for the OP. Once he/she gets a grasp of this, will surely look into jQuery.

Comment: @lcarus: Thanks for your help... I'll mark your answer once I have it implemented...May take a while though :(

Comment: @user1028488: no problem. You can do that across your website *mostly* without involving a single line of code change. It's not the panacea but it will definitely be better than regular postbacks.

Comment: @Icarus: If we know better than to use `UpdatePanel` but still recommend it to inexperience developers, aren't we just encouraging bad implementations that we later complain about?

Comment: @R0MANARMY: You are right. Will post the other alternative in a minute.

Comment: @Icarus: you're a better man than I am.  Which is why you're answering questions and I'm just commenting =).

Comment: @R0MANARMY: Posted some code. I don't know how useful will be, though. I had to remove a lot stuff to make it simpler.

Comment: @R0MANARMY: I was just being a bit lazy, but realistically, though, I don't think the OP will go for the jQuery approach from the start. It's a steeper learning curve and is not so easy to get it right the first time. In any case, I hope the pointers are helpful.

Comment: @Icarus: I guess it comes down to answering the question that **was** asked, or answering the question that **should have been** asked.  Either way, thank you for helping stop the abuse of UpdatePanel.

Comment: @lcarus: thnks a lot, I am trying the jquery approach.. But I am having a difficult time using the path of the usercontrol(as I explained, my Gridview is a user control) as URL... Somehow I am having trouble there

Answer (score 0):

Put the `GridView` into the `asp:UpdatePanel`. All the postbacks involving the Grid will change to callbacks and your grid should be updated without reloading the whole page.